# Checked checkbox change specific td background color in tr

Tags: javascript

I want to change the background color of the td when I checked the checkbox. But I don't know how to make it done. Please help me.

Each tr will consist a row of data. And each data part will have a checkbox which allow user to check it to highlight those specific data only.

[image: This is the example of the image]

I want to make it look like this.[image: Only the first 2 td background change]

```js
//The script is empty because I don't know how to write
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 10%;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>6</th>
                <th>7</th>
                <th>8</th>
                <th>9</th>
            </tr>
            <% for(let a = 0; a < 10; a ++){ %>
                <tr>
                    <td id="first">X</td>
                    <td id="first">X</td>
                    <td id="first"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the need of any data attributes and assuming you want to mark a specific group of cells together, you can do something like this:

- Select all input triggers
- Attach an eventListener to each one of them with 'change'
- For the index of each triggered input, adjust with the variable 'markUpTo' how many cells you want to mark from the start. Keep in mind the index limits.
- Toggle a 'selected' class up to that point that will handle the background color change.
- With this method you can easily scale this solution to include groups of 4,5,6 etc...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input').forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener("change", () => {

    // If first button changed, it is also the last
    let startingIndex = 0;
    let endingIndex = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input')[0].dataset.group) - 1;

    // If anything else, we need to calculate the correct start/end indexes
    if (i !== 0) {
      for (let y = 0; y < i; y++) {
        startingIndex += parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input')[y].dataset.group);
        endingIndex += parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input')[y + 1].dataset.group);
      }
    }

    for (let a = startingIndex; a <= endingIndex; a++) document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td')[a].classList.toggle('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
    <th>13</th>
    <th>14</th>
    <th>15</th>
    <th>16</th>
    <th>17</th>
    <th>18</th>
    <th>19</th>
    <th>20</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=2 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=4 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=5 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=6 type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-group=1 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=4 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=4 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=5 type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I want but can't find it anywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @Xylex You're welcome. Not sure why you didn't accept this as the best answer though.

Comment: This solution only works if you have fixed length data. So this solution is not very flexible

Comment: @DevQuayle depends on what you mean by flexible. OP did not state that the groups will be of different length. This solution IS flexible for groups of the same length, no matter their length. I prefer not to bloat HTML with data-attrs when there is no special reason.

Comment: 1 question. The background only change when I click the checkbox. That Is what I want at first which is already solved. 
What if there a button that once click all checkbox will be checked. 
I try adding that function and the checkbox got checked but the background won't change. I post another question. Please help me out a bit.

Comment: @Xylex that's easy to do, I'll check your post.

Comment: I posted it. Add on version of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486957/checked-checkbox-for-specific-td-that-works-with-filter-button

Comment: @Xylex Since @DevQuayle called this not so flexible, I went ahead and implemented variable cell group length. All you have to do is assign a `data-group=x` to the input to define the group-length. Check the Demo Snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could use that in my project as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attribute to mark group of your data

Something like this

```js
    const addClass = elements => {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
       elements[i].classList.add('selected');
    }}

    const removeClass = elements => {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
       elements[i].classList.remove('selected');
    }}

    let cbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    cbox.forEach(box => {
      box.addEventListener('change', evt => {
        const dataKey = evt.target.value;
        const tdWithDataKey = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-key="${dataKey}"]`);

        if(evt.target.checked) {
           addClass(tdWithDataKey);
        } else {
          removeClass(tdWithDataKey);
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 10%;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td data-key="1">X</td>
                <td data-key="1">X</td>
                <td data-key="1">X</td>
                <td data-key="1"><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
               
                <td data-key="2">X</td>
                <td data-key="2"><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
               <td data-key="3">X</td>
                <td data-key="3">X</td>
                <td data-key="3"><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
            </tr>
      
       <tr>
                <td data-key="1a">X</td>
                <td data-key="1a">X</td>
                <td data-key="1a">X</td>
                <td data-key="1a"><input type="checkbox" value="1a"></td>
                
                <td data-key="2a">X</td>
                <td data-key="2a"><input type="checkbox" value="2a"></td>
               <td data-key="3a">X</td>
                <td data-key="3a">X</td>
                <td data-key="3a"><input type="checkbox" value="3a"></td>
            </tr>
     
     
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible using for loop on the tr and getting the same result. Let say I have around 10 to 50 data. Can I still using the same method to apply on it?

Comment: of course you can

Comment: Alright. I will give it a go.