# Checked checkbox for specific td that works with filter button

Tags: javascript

I have post a question which is this one [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74485941/checked-checkbox-change-specific-td-background-color-in-tr/74486271?noredirect=1#comment131488526_74486271). And there another thing that I want to add but the td background won't change without pressing the checkbox directly.

-Specific td background will change once checkbox is checked.
-But if I press a button which will check all the checkbox. The background won't change.

```
====ejs code====

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='formMassCheckIn'>
            <input type='button' value='Check All' onclick='js_select_all(this)'/> 
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                </tr>
                <% for(let a = 0; a < 10; a ++){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="first">X</td>
                        <td id="first">X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  name='circSelected'></td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  name='circSelected'></td>                </tr>
                <% } %>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
====javascript====

function js_select_all(btn){
    if (btn.value == "Check All") 
    {
        for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
        if(!document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)
            document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = true;
        
        }
        btn.value ="Uncheck All";
    } else 
    {
        for (var i=0 ; i < document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected.length ; i++) {
        if (document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked)
            document.formMassCheckIn.circSelected[i].checked = false;
        }
        btn.value = "Check All";
    } 
    }   

    const markUpTo = 5;
    
    document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input').forEach((btn, i) => {
        btn.addEventListener("change", () => {
            for(let a = i * markUpTo; a < (i * markUpTo + markUpTo); a ++){
                document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td')[a].classList.toggle('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

```
====css====

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 10%;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

Able to change specific td background.

-Directly check the checkbox or click the filter button(check all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Code

Try this:

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

cells.forEach((cell, i) => {
  if (cell.querySelector('input')) {
    const input = cell.querySelector('input');
    input.addEventListener("change", () => {
      for (let a = i - input.dataset.group + 1; a < i + 1; a++) document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td')[a].classList.toggle('selected');
    });
  }
});

// Simulate a click for all inputs
const checkAllBoxes = () => document.querySelectorAll('#myTable input').forEach(input => input.click());

// Attach the event on input
document.getElementById('checkAll').addEventListener('click', () => checkAllBoxes());
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <input type='button' value='Check / Uncheck All' id='checkAll' />
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
    <th>13</th>
    <th>14</th>
    <th>15</th>
    <th>16</th>
    <th>17</th>
    <th>18</th>
    <th>19</th>
    <th>20</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=2 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=4 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=5 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=5 type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-group=1 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=4 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=3 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=2 type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td><input data-group=5 type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That quick. Thanks for the help. I will accept your answer after the 10min. Really apricate it for the quick reply.

Comment: @Xylex You're welcome! I'll take a look at your previous question to try to include a way to include groups of different length. E.g. if you need to have first group of X cells, second group of Y cells. If I find a clean solution, I'll ping you.

Comment: Sure. That will be a lot of help.

Comment: I found a bug using your code. For example:

Example Example X X X 口 X X X 口

If the arrange is like that and the markupTo is 4. The background will change weirdly. The Example Example will be something like the item number or name.

Comment: After define the `data-group=4`. The background change but not one the X X X part. It start from the very beginning. `(Example X X X ) 口`. I thought it will go with `Example ( X X X 口 )`. @George

Comment: @Xylex you are right, just tested it. This was not mentioned in your post so I didn't include this possibility. It can be done though by grabbing the index of `<input>` and value of `data-group` and doing a loop from `data-group` to `index+1`. I don't have time right now to write this, if you can manage it go ahead, otherwise I'll ping you later.

Comment: I will try to manage it. But it will be nice for you to ping it to me afterward in case I can't manage it myself. But I try my best.

Comment: @Xylex please take a look at the updated code. I think you are good to go.